# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when running create sequence commands

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle

I'm trying to execute some sql using the following C# code:

```
IDbCommand objOracleCommand = CreateCommand(commandPart, connection, transaction);
objOracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm getting back a "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error.

commandPart is a string that looks like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_1
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
NOMAXVALUE
NOMINVALUE
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE
NOORDER

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_2 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
```

The commandPart is actually being read in from a text file.  The original SQL has semi-colons like so:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_1
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
NOMAXVALUE
NOMINVALUE
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE
NOORDER;

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_2 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

This original snippet (with semi-colons) will run just fine in SQL Developer.  If I run the original snippet via C# I get "ora-00911: invalid character".  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Try putting a semi-colon after NOORDER.  If that doesn't fix it, try separating the two statements and execute them one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Your command part consists of two commands. Oracle is confused because it only expects one command.

You'll need to execute (`ExecuteNonQuery`) the two commands seperately.

Comment: Hi,

I put a ; at the end I get a ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

I put a ; in between the two queries and I get a ora-00911: invalid character error.

I'm parsing a 300,000+ line sql file that's creating a blank database with my company's metadata.  If I split it at the semi colons, It works until I get to function creation statements that have lots of statements, separated by semicolons.
If I keep going down this route it seems I'll essentially wind up writing my own SQL parser.  I have a hard time believe that Oracle can't handle multiple sql statements in a sql command.

-Eric

Comment: For your purpose, it's better to use SQL*plus. It'll correctly split and execute the commands including blocks of PL/SQL, stored procedures etc. If you do the splitting yourself, the rule is to split at semicolons except when you encounter DECLARE or BEGIN; then you'll have to split at the next slash (/) on a separate line. (Oracle has three languages: SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*plus. The slash is part of SQL*plus only.)